# Controlling network traffic running pyspark in local mode?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running my preprocessing routine with pyspark in local mode on 12 core mac pro machine. Although I run it as a local mode with --master local[*], I suspect the network traffic actually touches my router so that overall network speed becomes slower.

I thought about blocking some ports used by spark from the local machine through the firewall but I believe there might be some better way to handle this.

I'm not sure whether my hypothesis on increased network traffic is right or wrong so I'd love to hear how others experienced. If so, is there any way to handle this with the configuration file instead?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just close your network or wifi?

Comment: @howie that could be an option but I still need to access the local machine via 80 port and 4040 port from remote. Thanks for the suggestion anyway